# Mail merge using Access query containing long text fields - long text fields are empty in word document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-access, mail-merge

I am trying to do a mail merge in an MS Word document based upon an MS Access query that contains long text fields.  For some reason, the entries in the long text fields do not show up in the Word document. Do I need to format the mergefield is some special way to have the long-text-field entry appear in the word document?

Comment: This post suggests that there is a limit of 255 characters on fields when doing a mail merge from Excel which is likely to be the same for MS-Access - https://superuser.com/questions/1219149/mail-merge-from-excel-to-word-field-is-formula-referring-to-text-255-character?rq=1